# Center align a div horizontally using default Twitter Bootstrap CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I know how to center align a div horizontally in CSS. You need to make the width to something less than 100% and have auto margin on both left and right sides. I want to do this default styles of Twitter Bootstrap. I don't want to write additional CSS. Wondering whether it's possible to achieve using default style used in Twitter Bootstrap.

To set width of the div, I am using `span*`. But `span*` is `float: left`. Is there any class, which can set the width of the div, but will not add `float: left`?

Comment: Can you post wat you have tried ? or create a jsfiddle .

Comment: It seems that because all grid elements are floated left, there's no way to center them and their contents without writing some custom styles. That said, how can a person build a site without doing so?

Comment: You can remove floating by adding the class '.clearfix'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To horizontally align a div that is using an even span styles (span2, span4, etc...), you need to use offset.

```
<div class="offset3 span6">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: What if the content to be centered is in a span1, span3, span5, span7, span9 or span11?

Comment: If it's an odd span and you have to stick with that exact span size, then you will need to resort to adding some custom CSS.

Answer (score 3):

Use class `pagination-centered`  inside a div like :

```
   <div class="row">
    <div class="span12 pagination-centered">
    <p> content</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The OP is asking about Bootstrap classes, not raw HTML.

Comment: @isherwood mind you .. i didnt gave him the html .. those where css property.

Comment: CSS properties are actually HTML. Again, the OP was asking for classes.

Comment: oh really ... what tag is text-align , never saw that till now in html .I wrote text-align:center (css property).. for your reference :http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp

Comment: "text-align" is a property of the style attribute of a given tag. In other words, it's HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap's way to center content seems to be by assigning `class="center-block"` to it: [a link to Bootstrap 3 doc page](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-center).

However, it won't work on a heading or a paragraph. `class="text-center"` seems to work in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

If the element you want to align horizontal is an odd span (@JayGee) and you don´t want to write additional CSS (not even inline?) then the answer should be: No, that´s not possible. Otherwise I´d go for @JayGee´s answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @JayGee's answer.

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
     ... content here ...
     </div>
</div>
```